# Chaos path weapon scaling

Tags: dark-souls

Let's say I have a Claymore sword, which I believe scales with Intelligence. If I upgrade that sword to Chaos, will it now scale with both Intelligence and Humanity, or just Humanity?

This question really applies to all weapons, I just used the claymore as an example.

Comment: Humanity scaling of all sorts was bugged and did not work in the release version of the game, so information about it might be hard to come by.

Answer (score 2):

The [**Claymore**](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/claymore) doesn't scale with Intelligence, it scales with Strength and Dexterity (each with a rating of C). A ***Magic* Claymore** will scale with Intelligence though.

You can't directly upgrade from a **Magic Claymore** to a **Chaos Claymore** though -- they are completely different upgrade paths. You would have to first remove the **Magic** upgrade first, then apply the **Chaos** upgrade. You can't create a weapon which scales like a **Magic** weapon and a **Chaos** weapon at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

YellowMegaMan is correct.  A Chaos weapon will scale with Humanity as well as with whatever stats the weapon would scale with in its 'normal' form.

If you check the weapon's stats on the equipment screen, you will see which stats it scales with; if you upgrade it to a Chaos weapon, it will scale with these as well as with Humanity (I'm not sure about this, but the *amount* by which it scales with these stats may be affected upon upgrading).  If there's any doubt, open the upgrade interface with the desired weapon, select the Chaos option, and you can see how stat scaling will be affected by upgrading your weapon.